# CSS height issue with flex box inside flex box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I am having a problem with flex boxes contained inside flex boxes. The JS Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/fr077nn2/ contains the following code:

```css
    #container{
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: 3px solid yellow;
    }
    .app {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid black;
    }
    .app-header {
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
    .app-content {
      border: 3px solid green;
      flex: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .app-footer {
      border: 3px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="container">
      <div class="app">
        <div class="app-header">HEADER1</div>
        <div class="app-content">
          <div class="app">
            <div class="app-header">HEADER2</div>
            <div class="app-content">CONTENT2</div>
            <div class="app-footer">FOOTER2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="app-footer">FOOTER1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the .app-content DIVs fill up the remaining space of the parent .app DIV. It works well for the outer boxes, as shown in the fiddle. However, for the inner boxes, CONTENT2 is not filling the remaining space. I suspect that height:100% does not work in that case because the height of the parent DIV is not properly known... any suggestion how to achieve the above properly?

**Edit:** Works fine on Firefox as expected not on Chrome.

Comment: Works fine on Firefox, the problem is on Chrome.

Comment: Added height: 100% on the .app-content worked fine... unless I am missing something? (viewed in Chrome) Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqjx0wr8/2/

Comment: @crazymatt this does not yield the expected output: adding 100% on .app-content will make that div use more space that just the remaining space, that is 100% of the parent, therefore pushing the footer outside. The goal is to have .app-content use only the remaining space.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py you are right, it seems to work well on FF34 and IE11. WTH Chrome...?

Comment: Is using JavaScript an option?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Unfortunately, no. I would like to stick to CSS here. In any case, if Chrome/webkit is not fully compliant, I would rather not use it on production websites for now.

Comment: Your re-use of class names makes this unneccessarily confusing... regardless, your code is almost correct. I've fixed the CSS up for you in [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkem4r6q/)

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, 100% height works when the parent has a well defined height. In your example, the outermost app-content does not have an explicit height which is why 100% height on its child does not work.

A simple workaround is to use relative-absolute positioning to size the child:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.app-header {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.app-content {
  border: 3px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  /* added property */
  position: relative;
}
.app-footer {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
/* added rule */
.app-content > .app {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* scrollbar and border correction */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app-header">HEADER1</div>
    <div class="app-content">
      <div class="app">
        <div class="app-header">HEADER2</div>
        <div class="app-content">CONTENT2</div>
        <div class="app-footer">FOOTER2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-footer">FOOTER1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, just solved what I've been trying to do the whole day. Would upvote 10 times if I could :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is OK / fit your needs, but at least it is flexing in Chrome + FF ;P Perhaps a nesting issue.

Flex on container + flex on content:

http://jsfiddle.net/fr077nn2/2/

```
#container{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.app-header {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.app-content {
  border: 3px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.app-footer {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a great workaround for Chrome, although I don't understand why the addition of display:flex along the entire DIV chain makes things work here... conceptually, having display: flex in .app-content does not make sense.

Comment: @Nick: I have been looking at this, and somewhat perplexed myself. I've had some issues with flex on chrome myself – and ended up with some hackish solutions. I've tried to find some good doc's on it but have have ended up short thus far.

Answer (score 1):

## Why not simplify?

### Using your current markup

This seems like a lot of unnecessary HTML.

You need to nest the flex all the way down. In this example, the top flex container has `height: 100vh` to take up the entire height of the viewport. Some of the flex children are also flex parents, they get `display: flex` along with `flex: 1` so they will grow and shrink and their children can expand.

#### Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.app-header {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.app-content {
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.app-footer {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app-header">HEADER1</div>
    <div class="app-content">
      <div class="app">
        <div class="app-header">HEADER2</div>
        <div class="app-content">CONTENT2</div>
        <div class="app-footer">FOOTER2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-footer">FOOTER1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Simplified Example

We can drastically reduce the markup and eliminate the need to nest the flex. The content is given `flex: 1` and will expand to fill all the space left over from the headers and footers.

In this example, the body itself is the flex container, this could be replaced with a top-level div wrapper.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.app-header {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.app-content {
  border: 3px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}
.app-footer {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-header">HEADER1</div>

<div class="app-header">HEADER2</div>

<div class="app-content">CONTENT2</div>

<div class="app-footer">FOOTER2</div>

<div class="app-footer">FOOTER1</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific in the description. The HTML DIVs do matter, they were supposed to represent various levels of nested shells (in practice, more than 1), say, inserted dynamically, and for which headers/footers could be dynamically removed or hidden.